# How can a variable be null in this piece of code?

Tags: java, findbugs

FindBugs complains about *Possible null pointer dereference of str1 on branch that might be infeasible in Comparator.compareStrings(String, String)* in this method:

```
private static int compareStrings(final String str1, final String str2) {
    if ((str1 == null) && (str2 == null)) {
        return COMPARE_ABSENT;
    }
    if ((str1 == null) && (str2 != null)) {
        return COMPARE_DIFFERS;
    }
    if ((str1 != null) && (str2 == null)) {
        return COMPARE_DIFFERS;
    }
    return str1.equals(str2) ? COMPARE_EQUALS : COMPARE_DIFFERS;
}
```

In Eclipse, I also see a warning on the last line (`str1` may be null).

Under what circumstances can `str1`  be `null` in `return str1.equals(str2) ? COMPARE_EQUALS : COMPARE_DIFFERS;` (given that the first two if blocks cover the situations, when `str1` is null) ?

Comment: It can't, but Eclipse isn't smart enough to tell.

Comment: (Personally, I prefer to disable that warning. It leads to excessively defensive code)

Comment: (Also, why not just use `Objects.equals`?)

Comment: Unrelated but: the second and third `if` can be combined into a single one: `if (str1 == null || str2 == null) return COMPARE_DIFFERS;`

Comment: I think @immibis is right while comparing object values it is better to use equals then "=="

Comment: btw you don't have to test whether `str2` is `null`. If it is `null` `str1.equals(str2)` must return `false`.

Comment: @blackOcean No, equals and == do different things. What I meant there is that the asker's *entire method* does exactly the same thing as `java.util.Objects.equals(Object, Object)` (not to be confused with `java.lang.Object.equals(Object)`)

Comment: While this question may be a duplicate of some question, it has no relation to the question is was marked as duplicate of.

Comment: @Eran, seems like it was somehow marked automatically. Voted for reopening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can avoid the warning by rearranging the if statements :

```
private static int compareStrings(final String str1, final String str2) {
    if (str1 == null) {
        if (str2 == null)) {
            return COMPARE_ABSENT;
        } else {
            return COMPARE_DIFFERS;
        }
    } else {
        if (str2 == null)) {
            return COMPARE_DIFFERS;
        } else {
            return str1.equals(str2) ? COMPARE_EQUALS : COMPARE_DIFFERS;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: return str1 == null ? (str2 == null ? COMPARE_ABSENT : COMPARE_DIFFERS) : (str1.equals(str2) ? COMPARE_EQUALS : COMPARE_DIFFERS);// a more short answer

Comment: @Harry.Chen But is it more readable? I guess that's a matter of opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

At the point where you call `str1.equals(str2)`, `str1` **cannot** be `null`. You should suppress this warning at that location.